# JQuery classes obstacles

Tags: jquery, class

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJxqx.png

I just started to learn Jquery and I decided to make the game Bomberman.

I am stuck with 1 big problem:
My litle guy has to stop in front of the obstacles so he can't go throught them
but with my code he only stops on the obstacle that is placed on top (also the first added)

In my code I try to say that he checks with each class (thats why i didnt use id) but this won't work. I also tried to fix it with "Each" but that just bugged everything.

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$("#Main").append('<div id="Player"></div>');
$("#Main").append('<div id="test1" class="Bottel" style="absolute; top:0px; left: 100px;"></div>');
$("#Main").append('<div id="test2" class="Bottel" style="absolute; top:30px; left: 100px;"></div>');
$("#Main").append('<div id="test3" class="Bottel" style="absolute; top:100px; left: 100px;"></div>');
$("#Main").append('<div id="test4" class="Bottel" style="absolute; top:200px; left: 100px;"></div>');
$("#Main").append('<div id="test5" class="Bottel" style="absolute; top:200px; left: 200px;"></div>');
//$(".Bottel").css('left',100 + 'px');



movement()
```

function movement(){

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {




    var position = $("#Player").position();
    var min = 270;

    switch (e.keyCode){
        case 37: 



            if (position.left >= 1) //&& $(".Bottel").position().left -44 >= position.left) 
            {
            if (($("div[class^='Bottel']").position().left +44 <= position.left) || ($("div[class^='Bottel']").position().left  >= position.left) || ($("div[class^='Bottel']").position().top + 35 <= position.top )){
            $("#Player").css('left',(position.left) - 20 + 'px');
            $("#Player").css('background','url(left.png) no-repeat');
            //});
            }
            else{
            //alert("test");
            //alert("test");
                //position = $("#Player").position();
            $("#Player").css('left',(position.left) + 'px');
            $("#Player").css('background','url(left.png) no-repeat');

            }

            }



            break;
        case 38: 

            if (position.top >= 1 ){
            if ($(".Bottel").position().left + 35 <= position.left || $(".Bottel").position().left - 40  >= position.left || $(".Bottel").position().top + 41 <= position.top ){
            $("#Player").css('top',(position.top) - 20 + 'px');
            $("#Player").css('background','url(top.png) no-repeat');
            }
            else{
            $("#Player").css('top',(position.top) + 'px');
            $("#Player").css('background','url(top.png) no-repeat');
            }
            //$("#Player").css('top',position.top - 20 + 'px');
            //$("#Player").css('background','url(top.png) no-repeat');
            }


            break;
        case 39: 
        //$.each($("#Main .Bottel"), function(i, .Bottel) { 
        //var location = $(".Bottel").position().left;
        //alert(location + ",");
        //alert(position().left);

            if (position.left <= 452 - 33) //&& $(".Bottel").position().left -44 >= position.left)

            {
            if ($(".Bottel").position().left -44 >= position.left || $(".Bottel").position().top + 35 <= position.top || $(".Bottel").position().left <= position.left ){
            $("#Player").css('left',(position.left) + 20 + 'px');
            $("#Player").css('background','url(right.png) no-repeat');
            }
            else{
            $("#Player").css('left',(position.left) + 'px');
            $("#Player").css('background','url(right.png) no-repeat');
            }
            }
            //});

            break;
        case 40: 

            if (position.top <= 393 - 41){
            $("#Player").css('top',position.top + 20 + 'px');
            $("#Player").css('background','url(bottem.png) no-repeat');             
            }


        break;
    }
});
```

}

Comment: Sounds like a fun project! =)

Answer (score 0):

`each()` is the right way to go.  Something like:

```
case 37:

  if (position.left > 0) {

    var canGoLeft = true;

    $('.Bottel').each(function() {
      var obstaclePosition = $(this).position();
      if (...collision detection code...) {
        canGoLeft = false;
        // optional: chuck 'return false;' in here to stop the each loop early 
      }
    });

    if (canGoLeft) {
      $("#Player").css({
        'left': (position.left) - 20 + 'px',
        'background':'url(left.png) no-repeat'
      });
    } else {
      $("#Player").css({
        'left': (position.left) + 'px',
        'background':'url(left.png) no-repeat'
      });
    }
  }

  break;
```

The 'collision detection code' would use `this` to refer to the current obstacle you're checking, e.g.:

```
    if ((obstaclePosition.left +44 <= position.left) || (obstaclePosition.left  >= position.left) || (obstaclePosition.top + 35 <= position.top )){
```

Note: I think your collision detection code probably needs a bit more work to account for the obstacle's height.